# How to fire an event when mouse hover over a specific text in AvalonEdit?

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I have an `AvalonEdit` WPF based application.

I want to define a specific behaviour when the user hovers with the mouse over a specific text in the editor, similar to `tag_binding` with python `tkinter`.

I googled around, and couldn't find any way to do this.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar here http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/p/9113/25353.aspx

The gist seems to be that at this time (2010!) there where no direct way to do it, but the following hint was given.

> There's no built-in tooltip support, but long ago I've added the
>   TextEditor.MouseHover event which can be used to show tool tips.

Example code:

```
    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();

    void TextEditorMouseHover(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var pos = textEditor.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetPosition(textEditor));
        if (pos != null) {
            toolTip.PlacementTarget = this; // required for property inheritance
            toolTip.Content = pos.ToString();
            toolTip.IsOpen = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    void TextEditorMouseHoverStopped(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        toolTip.IsOpen = false;
    }
```